# ModelState null when Controller instantiated by unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm trying to unit test my controller which contains a check for ModelState.IsValid but for some reason whatever I do I always end up with an null exception everywhere I try to access the ModelState (both in unit test and controller function).

Everywhere I check people just use the ModelState.Clear()/.AddModelError() and it seems to work for them. Some have said that they get an exception when the mvc versions differ but I have checked that and they were the same.

What can I be missing?

Heres the unit test code:

```
private Mock<IRegistrationService> registrationService;
    private RegistrationController registrationCtrl;

    public RegisteringANewUser()
    {
        registrationService = new Mock<IRegistrationService>();
        registrationCtrl = new RegistrationController(registrationService.Object);
        registrationCtrl.ModelState.Clear(); <- throws exception
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldRegisterUser_WhenInputIsCorrect()
    {

        var registration = RegistrationHelper.CreateRegistrationVM("username", "password", "asfa@asf.com");

        registrationCtrl.Post(registration);

        registrationService.Verify(s => s.Register(registration), Times.Once);
    }
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldReturnBadRequest_WhenInputIsInvalid()
    {
        var registration = RegistrationHelper.CreateRegistrationVM("", "", "");
        registrationCtrl.ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Error"); <- throws exception
        var result = registrationCtrl.Post(registration);

        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result.StatusCode);
    }
```

The controller function under test:

```
public HttpStatusCodeResult Post(RegistrationVM registration)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) <- throws exception
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        _registrationService.Register(registration);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

project.json for unit test library:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "Web": "1.0.0-*",
    "Moq": "4.2.1409.1722",
    "Xunit.KRunner": "1.0.0-rc1-10618",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1"
},

"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    }

},
"commands": {
    "test": "Xunit.KRunner"
}
}
```

And for the web site project:

```
{
/* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    //"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta1",
    "mongocsharpdriver": "1.10.0.0-rc1"
},
"commands": {
    /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { },
    "aspnetcore50": { } <- tried to remove this as I dont have it in my unit test lib without success
},
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
],
"packExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
}
}
```

Comment: In your action method, do you really mean to execute your bad request logic if the modelstate _is_ valid? Or should your code instead be `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` emphasis on the `!`?  (Maybe this was intentional but looked odd to me at first glance.)

Comment: Oops! Good that I'm trying to write a test for this!

Comment: Am a little confused about the question. Are you saying that when you run that particular test shown above, and the test executes your action method, an exception is thrown on the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` line in your controller? And you're saying that it also happens if you execute that action method outside of the unit test (like trigger it thru the UI)? You mentioned using `.AddModelError()` for your test; but I don't see that particular test in your question.

Comment: Your right except for the UI part. I ment inside controller code and inside the unit test code. I added one more unit test and changed the constructor to what I have tried and added comments where it throws exception

Comment: If that's the case, the root of the problem seems to be the ModelState is null when the Controller is instantiated by unit tests instead of by the framework. I don't have an answer but I would set breakpoints immediately after you instantiate the controller in the `RegisteringANewUser()` constructor, check Locals, and see if any other controller properties are null or if it's just ModelState. I would recommend an edit and re-title of your question, something to the effect of "ModelState null when Controller instantiated by unit test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a gap (until beta3). Was tracked by this [Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/mvc/issues/1771)

In Beta3 release (or you can just get at the dev builds in a day or so), we are going to initialize a unit testing only `ViewDataDictionary` so that your unit test will get an empty `ModelState`.

Here is a the new code snippet from `Controller.cs`

```
    [Activate]
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_viewData == null)
            {
                // This should run only for the controller unit test scenarios
                _viewData =
                    new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                                            ActionContext?.ModelState ?? new ModelStateDictionary());
            }

            return _viewData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw
                    new ArgumentException(Resources.ArgumentCannotBeNullOrEmpty, nameof(ViewData));
            }

            _viewData = value;
        }
    }
```

And (no change to the code)

```
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewData?.ModelState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the link to the PR is gone

Comment: Thanks @MaurizioIndenmark. The code made it in obviously. I'll remove the link